# how to fetch images from custom table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

how to fetch images from custom table in wordpress?
I have a custom table where I have upload images in wordpress. Here is my code:

```
global $wpdb; 
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_wfu_log"; 
$user = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_wfu_log" ); 
echo '<table>
```

Comment: What is the relevance of your code with your question? You are getting the table name in variable "$table_name" but you are not using variable in the select query.

Comment: my custom table is like that:idlog,userid,uploaduserid,filepath,filesize,uploadid,filepath

Comment: sir tried but not able to fetch :  global $wpdb;
         $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_wfu_log";
         $user = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_wfu_log" );
         echo '<table>
        <tr>
    <th>PHOTO</th>
    <th>test</th>
   
  </tr>';
 foreach( $user as $user_data) {
  echo "<tr>
        <td>echo $user->filepath</td>
   
  </tr>";
 }
 echo '</table>';

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
global $wpdb; 
//$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_wfu_log"; 
$user = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_wfu_log" ); 
echo '<table> <tr> <th>PHOTO</th> <th>test</th> </tr>';

foreach( $user as $user_data) { 

    echo "<tr> <td><img src='{$user_data->filepath}'></td> </tr>"; 
} 

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: sir tried but not able to fetch :  global $wpdb;
         $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_wfu_log";
         $user = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_wfu_log" );
         echo '<table>
        <tr>
    <th>PHOTO</th>
    <th>test</th>
   
  </tr>';
 foreach( $user as $user_data) {
  echo "<tr>
        <td>echo $user->filepath</td>
   
  </tr>";
 }
 echo '</table>';

Comment: i got the result like this:/wp-content/uploads/slider-1.jpg ,but  i want to show image